# Running a php script in apache webserver

Tags: apache2, php

I have created a php script and saved it as script.php, located in the `/var/www` directory. I also have index.html file which has a form which requires the user to enter a value and submit with the code

```
<html><body><form action="script.php" method="post">
name<input type="text name="fname"">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body></html>
```

for testing purposes, i have set my script.php file to be like

```
<?php
echo "Could not read name";
?>
```

When i enter the url on the browser, i get the form and on clicking submit, it responds by saying the url `http://localhost/script.php` was not found. i would like to know the reason why this is so. The question extends to why i can run the php script on its own when i move it from `/var/www` to home folder and run it as `php -f script.php` yet when i paste the url `http://localhost/script.php` , it reports that the url has not been found

Comment: check the error log in `/var/log/apache2`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider what should i check for

Comment: anything related to "script.php"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi this what I have done and I have got success with your Idea.

here this is what I have done ,

**script.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo " welcome "

?>
</body>
</html>
```

**clickhere.html**

```
<html><body><form action="script.php" method="post">
name<input type="text name="fname"">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body></html>
```

I have placed that code with `sudo gedit` and written that code and saved at the location of `/var/www/`.

Then I have opened my browser ,and typed in my browser as `127.0.0.1/clickhere.html`

then I have got it [image]

and then I have clicked at that button [image]

Comment: I am using Ubuntu server, sorry i did not clarify, therefore i have used vi editor, does that create a problem

Comment: No editor is not at all a problem.give a try with chmod 755 /var/www/script.php and chmod 755 /var/www/clickhere.html and then try again.

Comment: Instead of using 127.0.0.1 can I connect to node via its static IP? @Ten-Coin

Comment: @Alper Yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

try this for your php echo statement

```
echo " welcome " . $_POST['fname'];
```

Also your HTML has quote mismatch for the input tag

```
<input type="text" name="fname">
```